# Searching assets from asset store in project view in Unity3d

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am trying to search assets by using project view in Unity, however, search assets from asset store option is not an option in my version. What is wrong?
[image]

I can only search the files in the project, not asset store. How can I search the asset store as well?

Comment: In the project settings have you maybe disabled the option `Show Asset Store
 search hits Enable this setting to show the number of free/paid Assets from the Asset Store in the Project Browser.` ? I think it's in the General settings

Answer (score 2):

You can find the assets store y going to Window < Panels < 1.Asset Store. Also make sure that you are on unity version 2020.3 or above to access the asset store in the Editor tab.

Answer (score 1):

You can search for Asset Store packages in either Asset Store window (Unity 2019 or older) or on the web. In Unity 2020 and newer you can't search for asset from within Unity Editor.

Once you add packages to your collection (purchase them or for free assets bookmark them), they will show up in the **Package Manager** window (window -> package manager). Make sure you change the filter to "My Assets" in Package Manager.

You can use the search box in Package Manager window to search in your assets only.